# Calling Auth0 from supeertest

Tags: mocha.js, auth0, supertest

I'm trying to adopt this example which uses 'request' and works properly, to supertest to be use with Mocha.

```js
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://domain.auth0.com/oauth/token",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  form: {
    grant_type: "password",
    username: "someone@email.com",
    password: "myPassword",
    audience: "https://some-place.com",
    client_id: "long-string",
    client_secret:
      "even-longer-string"
  }
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

I have tried the below which produces an error and doesn't send the request.

```js
import request from 'supertest'

describe('get a token', function () {
  it('should return an access token', async function() {
    const r = await request('https://domain.auth0.com/oauth/token')
      .post()
      .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .field('grant_type', 'password')
      .field('username', 'someone@email.com')
      .field('password', 'myPassword')
      .field('audience', 'https://some-place.com')
      .field('client_id', 'long-string')
      .field(
        'client_secret',
        'even-longer-string'
      )
      .send()
      .expect(200)
  })
})
```

Which results in the error

```
TypeError: (0 , _superagent.default)(...).post is not a function
```

Also tried to split the url between request() and post()

```js
import request from 'supertest'

describe('get a token', function () {
  it('should return an access token', async function() {
    const r = await request('https://domain.auth0.com/')
      .post('/oauth/token')
      .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

      ...

      .expect(200)
  })
})
```

Which results in

```js
Error: expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"
```

The server is Express.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import request from 'supertest'

describe('get a token', () => {
  it('should return an access token', async () => {
    const response = await request('https://domain.auth0.com')
      .post('/oauth/token')
      .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .field('grant_type', 'password')
      .field('username', 'someone@email.com')
      .field('password', 'myPassword')
      .field('audience', 'https://some-place.com')
      .field('client_id', 'long-string')
      .field('client_secret','even-longer-string')
      .expect(200)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion. I was away from this project for a bit and since asking the code base has changed enough that I can no longer try out your suggestion. The work-around implemented is to use 'request' to get the token and supertest to validate the token was received.